# How to use web3.js in Chrome extension's background.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web3js

I'm attempting to use web3.js in a Chrome extension's background.js file (manifest v3) like so:

```
// background.js

const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3("https://api.avax.network/ext/bc/C/rpc")

var abi = [
    {
      "constant": true,
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "owner",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "type": "address"
        }
      ],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "payable": false,
      "type": "constructor"
    }
  ];


var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
```

But I instantly receive the error that "window is not defined". I understand that Chrome background scripts don't have access to window, but I don't understand why attempting to instantiate web3 requires access to window.

[Screenshot of extension error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReO10.png)

I'm using webpack to bundle web3.js with background.js.

My goal is to make read calls to a contract from background.js, and figured web3.js was the easiest method.

Comment: This library is not compatible with workers. Ask the authors of the library to implement it.

Comment: @wOxxOm do you know of another way to query contracts and encode abi functions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but I was able to fix it by only installing `web3-eth` instead of all of `web3`.

```
const Eth = require('web3-eth');
...
const eth = new Eth(Eth.givenProvider || provider);
const contract = new eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

(I also had a few other issues because I mixed ES module syntax with CommonJS module syntax, but I was able to resolve them by changing my `import`s to `require`s.)

---

From the screenshot you attached, there's a warning that says your service worker wasn't registered. My `manifest.json` has the following snippet:

```
"background": {
  // replace this with the name of your entry file
  "service_worker": "index.js"
},
```